# virtual functions in static libraries

Tags: c++, static-linking, vtable

When I have an abstract base class `foo`, defined in `libX.a`

```
class foo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

... and a derived class `foo_impl`, defined in `libY.a`

```
class foo_impl : public foo {
    void bar() { /* do something */ }
};
```

... and use both libraries to link a program `-lX -lY`

```
int main() {
    foo* my_foo = receive_a_foo_from_somewhere();
    my_foo->bar();
}
```

Then

- how can I force the linker to actually link the symbol referring to `foo_impl::bar()`?
- does `objdump -t program` list `foo_impl::bar()` when it is correctly linked?

EDIT: to clarify, I am using linux with gcc or clang

EDIT 2: had missed `virtual` for `bar()`

EDIT 4: I apologize for missing clarity. The question should have been "how can I force the linker to actually include `foo_impl::bar()` in the executable so it can be resolved at runtime?"

Comment: how would he know where to link it to? it is a virtual method that requires dynamic lookup.

Comment: When the virtual table for `foo_impl` is created the member function `foo_impl` is tagged as having been used when an object of that type is instantiated. The linker will then automatically include it in your application.

Comment: EDIT 3: my_foo**->**bar();

Comment: Captain Obvlious, so in my case (I do not know which kind of `foo*` I receive), I would have to somewhere instantiate a dummy `foo_impl` to convince the compiler to include its functionality?

Comment: Is it that, `foo_impl` is the only implementation of `foo` and you want to make all calls to `foo::bar()` automatically translated to `foo_impl::bar()`? Then you need a static_cast. But in that case I suggest you make `foo_impl` parent of `foo`. If it's not the case, then force the linker to link the symbol referring to `foo_impl::bar()` will cause error when the `foo` is in fact not `foo_impl`.

Comment: no `foo_impl` is **one** implementation of `foo`

Comment: Then how could you know that `my_foo` points to a `foo_impl` and can safely call `foo_impl::bar()`?

Comment: because every `foo` must implement `bar()`

Comment: Every foo must implement `bar()`, but they can implement differently, not necessary to be `foo_impl::bar()` but can also be `another_foo_impl::bar()`.

Comment: Couldn't this just be a library order issue?  Does specifying `-lX -lY -lX` change the link errors at all?

Comment: Also, something actually being linked does potentially construct a `foo_impl`, I hope?

Comment: Not necessarily. When - for example - the `foo*` originates from a file containing an an abstract serialized `foo`, then there must obviously be some de-serialization code for (amongst others) `foo_impl`. But as long as no `foo_impl` is explicitly used, the de-serialization code might not be linked...

Comment: `foo::bar()` is declared private!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there are at least two ways to get the linker to include `foo_impl::bar()` functionality in the executable:

1. With gcc, one can use `-Wl,--whole-archive` to link an entire static library - no matter what.
2. As Captain Obvlious pointed out, when `foo_impl` is used in the program, it's virtual functions are tagged as having been used and are thus included in the executable. This could also be an otherwise useless static *dummy* `foo_impl` object.

Answer (score 0):

Since the bar method is defined as virtual, there is no need of static linking. The linking will be done dynamically at runtime based on the object type to which the *my_foo refers to. Regardless of whether it's defined in libX.a or libY.a.

Answer to you question how to force the linker to link the symbol referring to foo_impl::bar()?

You can't force the linker to link to particular implementation. The linking will happen based on which object address you got from receive_a_foo_from_somewhere().

Obviously the implementation should be linked to your exe. If it is not available it will definitely fail. But you can't force linker to link particular implementation,

Comment: ...which must fail because the compiler (linker actually) never included libY.a symbols

Comment: Answer to you question how to force the linker to link the symbol referring to foo_impl::bar()?

You can't force the linker to link to particular implementation. The linking will happen based on which object address you got from receive_a_foo_from_somewhere(). 

Obviously the implementation should be linked to your exe. If it is not available it will definitely fail. But you can't force linker to link particular implementation,

Comment: sorry, my mistake. see EDIT 4

Comment: @idefixs: Then your question is more related to options of gcc compiler to include your static library right? I believe there is nothing to do with virtual also. If you get option of gcc to include static libraries then your problem will be resolved?